# How to fill in columns from lists/arrays into an empty Pandas dataframe with only column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with several column names. As and when I get data for each column, I have to create rows. I don't have all the row data available in one place. As and when I get data for a column in a particular row, I will fill it

In this example below, I have created an empty dataframe and and I am trying to fill in a particular column with a set of values. This is not working.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

col_names = ['ampere', 'freq', 'count']
dataf = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_names)
freq = np.arange(0.6,2.6,0.1).tolist()
#Add the list of frequencies to the frequency column
dataf['freq'].iloc[1:len(freq)] = freq
```

The error I am getting is

ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 20 to array axis with dimension 0

Comment: You need to specify the size of your dataframe when you instantiate it

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there! There is no need for the `iloc`-indexing.

So just change your last line to

```py
dataf['freq'] = freq
```

and it should work as expected.

If you want to keep adding more rows from different lists, as you mentioned in the comment, you can use following code snippet:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

col_names = ['ampere', 'freq', 'count']
dataf = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_names)
freq = np.arange(0.6,2.6,0.1).tolist()
#Add the list of frequencies to the frequency column
dataf['freq'] = freq

freq2 = np.arange(7,70,1).tolist()

for i, value in enumerate(freq2, len(dataf)):
    dataf.loc[i] = [np.nan, value, np.nan]
```

I hope this helps to solve your problem.

Comment: This works. Howeever, if I have to keep appending to a column from various lists how do I achieve this ?

Comment: I updated the code to represent the problem you just commented :)